# Azure Devops pipeline, git authentication only works with -c http.extraheader

Tags: git, authentication, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to clone repositories in an Azure DevOps pipeline. When I provide the `System.AccessToken` inline with `git clone`, authentication works. But I don't want to provide this header but rather configure it so that credential manager can read that. Eventually I want to run `terraform init` command that will clone repositories without header provided inline.

Simply, the following line works:

- `git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"` 
  But without the `http.extraheader`, it does not work.

Additional notes:

- I set `persistCredentials: true` in the pipeline.
- I want to clone the same repository that the pipeline can initially clone to get the yml file.
- The build service has read access to the repository.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) and we don't need to add headers. Here is a sample for your reference.

Please note that, if you would use `git clone` command in a script to checkout a **non-self** repo (`RepoC` in my sample) in a YAML pipeline, please don't forget to disable `Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines`.

[image]

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    name: RepoA
    type: git

steps:
- checkout: self # TestRepo
- checkout: A
  path: RepoA
  displayName: Checkout RepoA
- checkout: git://$(TheProjectName)/RepoB
  path: RepoB
  displayName: Checkout RepoB
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Agent.BuildDirectory - $(Agent.BuildDirectory)"
    git clone https://$(AzureDevOpsOrgName):$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/$(AzureDevOpsOrgName)/$(TheProjectName)/_git/RepoC
    tree /F /A
  displayName: Checkout RepoC
  workingDirectory: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
```

[image]